# Clarification on Read and None LockMode in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, transactions

As per Read LockMode in Hibernate docs  **It is a shared lock. Objects in this lock mode were read from the database in the current transaction, rather than being pulled from a cache.**

```
     SessionFactory sessions = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
     Session session = sessions.openSession();
     Transaction tx = null;
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Person p1  = (Person)session. get(Person.class,1);//line 1
         p1  = (Person)session. get(Person.class,1);//line 2
         session. lock(p1, LockMode.READ);//line 3
         p1  = (Person)session. get(Person.class,1);//line4 
         p1  = (Person)session. get(Person.class,1);//line 5
```

Now as per shared lock definition **holding share locks to prevent concurrent access by a writer**    with the code snippet above , i made the thread to hold at line 4(so it has acquired the lock in read mode at this point of time).Now i tried to update the person with id 1 from another thread, it succeeded. Not sure why, because as per definition **holding share locks to prevent concurrent access by a writer**

As Read lock mode says **Objects in this lock mode were read from the database in the current transaction, rather than being pulled from a cache** . Bt in my code snippet at line 4 and line 5 it did not get the row from database for id 1, it got from session only.Why?

Last question on None Lock Mode. As per documentation **No lock required. If an object is requested with this lock mode, a READ lock will be obtained if it is necessary to actually read the state from the database, rather than pull it from a cache.**  As stated no lock acquired then why would developer acquire this lock, as this would be default. **Right?**

Comment: can you publish the **SQL queries** fired in the background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now i tried to update the person with id 1 from another thread, it
>   succeeded. Not sure why, because as per definition holding share locks
>   to prevent concurrent access by a writer

How about when a thread 1 is just about to write an entity to the database and thread 2 is going to read the same entity from it? Either one of them should get a lock to read or write the data. If thread1 gets the write lock, thread 2 must wait till the write is complete. However, if thread 2 gets the read lock, thread 1 has no problem in going in and writing the data. This is so because when thread 2 reads the records in a consistent state. It becomes stale only after thread 1 has written to the database (Although, a write on this object from thread 2 will trigger a stale state exception in case of a versioned entity). Read locks are meant for preventing inconsistency and not freeze the record for further update by the same transaction. You can achieve that behaviour using write locks.

> Last question on None Lock Mode. As per documentation No lock
>   required. If an object is requested with this lock mode, a READ lock
>   will be obtained if it is necessary to actually read the state from
>   the database, rather than pull it from a cache. As stated no lock
>   acquired then why would developer acquire this lock, as this would be
>   default. Right?

Again the read lock is accquired in order to prevent the entity to be in an inconsistent state. From the cache it wont be a problem. The developer does not need to specify the Read lock when doing a fetch, it should be managed internally by the persistence provider.